# Visual Studio jump to active thread in debugger

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

Breaking into a C++ program that has many threads, most of them paused in a wait state. It's too tedious cycling through the waiting threads in the IDE to find the ones that are active in the debugger.

Is there a way to jump to or sort or an indication in the IDE display to help quickly find the threads not waiting?

Comment: No.  You are not doing it right if you need to do this a lot.  Never use Debug > Break All to debug, set a breakpoint.  In other words, focus on a specific piece of code you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio jump to active thread in debugger

If I understand you correct, you could use the [Visual Studio Threads window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w15yf86f(v=vs.85).aspx) to see which threads are active.

> **To display the Threads window in break mode or run mode**
>
> - From the Debug menu, point to Windows, and then click Threads.
>
> **To set an active thread**
>
> - In the Threads window, right-click a thread,  and click Switch to    Thread on the shortcut menu.    -or-    Double-click the thread to
>     make it active.    A yellow arrow identifies the active thread.